# MiniDisplay to HDMI to VGA Issue

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, mini-displayport

I have a MBP 2010 that doesnt have a HDMI port, so I got a MiniDisplay to HDMI for a monitor I had. Currently, I'm using a monitor that only supports VGA. To use this monitor I have to connect the Minidisplay > HDMI > VGA but it doesnt seem to work.

Should it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- DP > HDMI is passive, it's the same signal in different connectors.
- HDMI > VGA requires digital > analogue conversion.

> To use this monitor I have to connect the Minidisplay > HDMI > VGA but it doesnt seem to work.
>
> Should it work?

**It depends**.

It depends mostly on the specific HDMI>VGA device you're using. If it's just a **port adapter** (cheap, passive, and useful for some non-standard applications/devices only) then no, it shouldn't. A **converter** (more expensive but providing the required digital>analogue signal conversion) should work but may not.

Generally it's better to have just a known good DP>VGA converter even if, technically speaking, there's nothing wrong with your configuration, assuming that the last device is actually a converter.