# dvi and vga dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I am trying to set up a dual monitor system on my PC that contains a DVI port and VGA port. the VGA port is connected to one monitor with a standard VGA cable. And the second monitor is connected to the DVI via a DVI to VGA adaptor, but my PC can't detect it. I've tried installing drivers for my integrated graphics but still, it won't detect the monitor.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You need a DVI to VGA converter. A simple adapter cable won't work. Please [edit] and post the exact characteristics of the device.

Comment: whats the difference between an adopter and a converter?

Comment: One is just a cable, the other converts analogue/digital. The same as I explained here: https://superuser.com/a/1353627/931000

Answer (score 0):

with the little information available and On the assumption that everything (s/w & h/w) is installed correctly;

If you head over to the wikipedia page for [Digital Visual Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface), there are a whole slew of versions. Some can work with a simple DVI-VGA Adapter;
You probably have lucked out and got one that doesn't convert it.

You did not say what sort of cable you are connecting the graphic card to your monitor. Is it a VGA or DVI cable ? There is the off chance the cable is not faulty; I have seen cables with just 1 pin crushed and the whole cable failed.

Your Monitor could be at fault too. Faulty VGA port. But I;m guessing it works with other computers.

So in summary, could be your cable, your adapter or your monitor.
I would start with a known good cable, then try a new adapter and finally loan a vga monitor or splurge and get one with a DVI connection.

Comment: The second monitor isn't being detected. It's not a matter of desktop settings. The problem is most likely the adapter the OP is using which ISN'T a converter. The discussion about it is in comments above.